# Create cards dynamically and arrange their layout using Flex

Tags: angular, css, flexbox, angular-material

I want to create mat-cards and have some content in it . The number of cards can vary depending on the content from the api (if api gives me data of 5 parameters 5 cards have to be created ) These cards have to aligned like 3 or 4 in a row. Tried googling how to do it but could not find. Can someone help me?

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
 </div>
```

This gives 5 elements in a row. I expected the 5th element to start in a new row because fxFlex percentage sum has reached 100%.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
 </div>

 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center">
    <app-tile fxFlex="25%"></app-tile>
 </div>
```

Works fine when I do it like this.

But how do I do this using ngFor when the number of cards changes dynamically?

Comment: Two things: 1. Use `*ngFor` to dynamically create the `mat-cards`. 2. Check for the `flex-wrap` property to allow content spilling into next row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `wrap` in the `fxLayout` attribute in your template:

```
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <div fxFlex="25%"></div>
  <div fxFlex="25%"></div>
  <div fxFlex="25%"></div>
  <div fxFlex="25%"></div>
  <div fxFlex="25%"></div>
</div>
```

See [**`stackblitz example here`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-er76rb).

Comment: layout items are dynamic in my case, maybe 2 or 3 or 4 items, should take equal space accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; justify-content:flex-start">
    <div *ngFor="let card of Cards">
        <mat-card style="width:YOUR-DESIRED-WIDTH"></mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have considered your cards as an array of cards.If we use flex like this, it will wrap the contents and auto aligns the cards based on the available screen estate.